# Storing a specific number of bits from a list of integers C#

Tags: c#, byte, type-conversion

I have a list of ints:

```
public List<int> binaryVector;
```

However I want to read in only the first 8 bytes of that integer and store it as a variable. Then I want to do the same for the next 24 bytes of that integer after that. All ints in the binary vector are of 32 bit. Any Idea on how I can do this?

the first 24 bits of the int is considered the value that the instruction is holding. the last 8 bits is a numerical value that if looked up in a hash table, gets translated to an instruction

Example:

lda #$5 // load the value into the accumulator

when converted to binary it is put into 32 bit int format and stored in the binary vector.
first 24 bits is the value stored, in this case the value 5. the last 8 bits are reserved for the instruction.

I want to read pieces of the 32 bit int and store them as variables. for example i want to read the first 24 bits of the example given above and store it as an int variable which should equal 5.

how i store instructions:

```
int IMM = 16777216;

int inst = instructionValue;

inst = inst | IMM;


inst = inst << 24;

inst = inst | value;
```

the 24 bits are the value, the 25 bit is like a boolean either 1 or 0 telling me if the value is an immediate. the last 7 bits are for the instruction

Comment: integers have 4 bytes on 32 bit code, so what do you mean by "the first 8 bytes of that integer" or "the next 24 bytes of that integer"? Are you talking about bits instead byte?

Comment: It's hard to guess what you're trying to do (to give a proper answer not based just on guess). I would take a look to **System.BitConverter** and **System.Collections.BitArray** for some useful stuff.

Comment: the 32 bit int serves as a instruction for my emulator. So a certain number of bytes in the 32 bit int specifies a certain instruction. I want to store a certain number of bits into a variable so I can decode part of the instruction.

Comment: Its hard to decipher what you want to do. So you say your binaryVector is a list of emulator instructions with the first byte of the int being the command? And please reread your question if you mixed up bits with bytes.

Comment: the first 24 bytes of the int is considered the value that the instruction is holding. the last 8 bytes is a numerical value that if looked up in a hash table, gets translated to an instruction.

Comment: So you are talking about **bits** not bytes.

Comment: yes sorry if i am confusing the two, been up all night

Comment: @user2510809 See my answer if I guessed your question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to extract the lower 24 bits from the integers into param and the upper 8 bits into command.

You can do that in the following way:

```
var param = binaryVector[i] & 0xffffff;
var command = (binaryVector[i] >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Feel free to replace `i` in the code with your "instruction pointer"

**Hint:** Be careful in the construction of the instruction integer that param not exceeds 24 bits. Your code should be protected for this case with a mask or you would destroy your command byte:

```
inst = inst | value & 0xffffff;
```

Comment: assuming we are reading the binary value from right to left? so the value is stored first, then we shift 8 places and are left with the last 8 bits to store?

Comment: @user2510809 My code assumes command is the lowest byte in the integer. The upper 3 bytes are param in this case.

Comment: @user2510809 See my edit, I added the build of the integer I splitted.

Comment: I am a little confused, I just edited my original post and added how I originally store the instruction in the binaryvector

Comment: @user2510809 After you made your question more precise I edited my answer to fit to your binary instruction.

Comment: I just made edit in the original post. turns out the 25 bit is a boolean value telling me if the value is an immeidate or not. How would I extract that one bit to see if it was a one or a zero?

Comment: The 25th bit is bit0 of the command, right? You can extract that with `var immediateFlag = (command & 1) == 1;` Your instruction layout `ccccccccpppppppppppppppppppppppp`. (c=command, p=param). Lowest c bit is your immediateflag as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create struct and define set variable in there:

Here is an example:

```
struct SimpleStruct
{
    private int xval;
    public int X
    {
        get 
        {
            // write what you need here
        }
        set 
        {
           // set your variable here
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can define your list :

```
public static List<SimpleStruct> myList{ get; private set; }
```

Or if you want to make it with method you can use such example:

```
public byte ReadFirstNBits(int n)
{
    Contract.Requires(n >= 0 && n <= 8, "Code contract may be too slow for your needs");
    byte val = base.ReadByte();
    return val >> (8 - n);
}
```

Comment: To wrap/hide/simplify what?

Comment: Just .copy your integer value.